# How to get the sub UL length

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
    <ul class="uSPStyle" id="uSPStyle">
    <li> <!-- 1st entry -->
        <a class="tfLink clickMe current" title="Healthy Measures" data-toggle=".tfLink4" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="theImages/imgMinus.png" id="imgFirstM" class="imgExpCol">Healthy Measures</a>
        <ul class="uSPStyle uSPInner" style="width: 80%; display: block;">
            <li><a class="tfLink clickMe current" title="What We Do" data-toggle=".tf1SLink4" href="javascript:void(0);">What We Do</a></li>
            <li><a class="tfLink clickMe" title="Our Team" data-toggle=".tf2SLink4" href="javascript:void(0);">Our Team</a></li>
            <li><a class="tfLink clickMe" title="Contact Us" data-toggle=".tf3SLink4" href="javascript:void(0);">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li style="display: none;"><a class="tfLink clickMe" title="" data-toggle=".tf4SLink4" href="javascript:void(0);"></a></li>
            <li style="display: none;"><a class="tfLink clickMe" title="" data-toggle=".tf5SLink4" href="javascript:void(0);"></a></li>
            <li style="display: none;"><a class="tfLink clickMe" title="" data-toggle=".tf6SLink4" href="javascript:void(0);"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <!-- 2nd entry -->
        <a class="tfLink clickMe current" title="Healthy Measures" data-toggle=".tfLink4" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="theImages/imgMinus.png" id="imgFirstM" class="imgExpCol">Healthy Measures</a>
        <ul class="uSPStyle uSPInner" style="width: 80%; display: block;">
            <li><a class="tfLink clickMe current" title="What We Do" data-toggle=".tf1SLink4" href="javascript:void(0);">What We Do</a></li>
            <li><a class="tfLink clickMe" title="Our Team" data-toggle=".tf2SLink4" href="javascript:void(0);">Our Team</a></li>
            <li><a class="tfLink clickMe" title="Contact Us" data-toggle=".tf3SLink4" href="javascript:void(0);">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li style="display: none;"><a class="tfLink clickMe" title="" data-toggle=".tf4SLink4" href="javascript:void(0);"></a></li>
            <li style="display: none;"><a class="tfLink clickMe" title="" data-toggle=".tf5SLink4" href="javascript:void(0);"></a></li>
            <li style="display: none;"><a class="tfLink clickMe" title="" data-toggle=".tf6SLink4" href="javascript:void(0);"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <!-- 3rd entry -->
        <a class="tfLink clickMe current" title="Healthy Measures" data-toggle=".tfLink4" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="theImages/imgMinus.png" id="imgFirstM" class="imgExpCol">Healthy Measures</a>
        <ul class="uSPStyle uSPInner" style="width: 80%; display: block;">
            <li><a class="tfLink clickMe current" title="What We Do" data-toggle=".tf1SLink4" href="javascript:void(0);">What We Do</a></li>
            <li><a class="tfLink clickMe" title="Our Team" data-toggle=".tf2SLink4" href="javascript:void(0);">Our Team</a></li>
            <li><a class="tfLink clickMe" title="Contact Us" data-toggle=".tf3SLink4" href="javascript:void(0);">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li style="display: none;"><a class="tfLink clickMe" title="" data-toggle=".tf4SLink4" href="javascript:void(0);"></a></li>
            <li style="display: none;"><a class="tfLink clickMe" title="" data-toggle=".tf5SLink4" href="javascript:void(0);"></a></li>
            <li style="display: none;"><a class="tfLink clickMe" title="" data-toggle=".tf6SLink4" href="javascript:void(0);"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <!-- 4th entry -->
        <a class="tfLink clickMe current" title="Healthy Measures" data-toggle=".tfLink4" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="theImages/imgMinus.png" id="imgFirstM" class="imgExpCol">Healthy Measures</a>
        <ul class="uSPStyle uSPInner" style="width: 80%; display: block;">
            <li><a class="tfLink clickMe current" title="What We Do" data-toggle=".tf1SLink4" href="javascript:void(0);">What We Do</a></li>
            <li><a class="tfLink clickMe" title="Our Team" data-toggle=".tf2SLink4" href="javascript:void(0);">Our Team</a></li>
            <li><a class="tfLink clickMe" title="Contact Us" data-toggle=".tf3SLink4" href="javascript:void(0);">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li style="display: none;"><a class="tfLink clickMe" title="" data-toggle=".tf4SLink4" href="javascript:void(0);"></a></li>
            <li style="display: none;"><a class="tfLink clickMe" title="" data-toggle=".tf5SLink4" href="javascript:void(0);"></a></li>
            <li style="display: none;"><a class="tfLink clickMe" title="" data-toggle=".tf6SLink4" href="javascript:void(0);"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to know the size of the inner UL inside the parent LI.

I am using the following code:

```
var vFirst = "3";
vULSubSize = $("#uSPStyle li:not(li li):eq(" + vFirst + ")").find("a").closest("li").children("ul").length; //{DONE}get the size of the sub UL inside the above LI
alert(vULSubSize); // keep displaying 1 [2 items] and not 2 [3 items]
```

How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: What's with the crazy selector and why do you expect three items instead of six?

Comment: I would mind getting all six but I am not even getting that :/

Comment: Your use of `:not` has me confused. Please explain in your question exactly what you're after.

Comment: The `:not` was so that I don't get the length of the parent UL.

Comment: `vFirst` is used to find out which parent LI I should check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the number of `li` descendants based on the fourth `li` child element, then you could use the direct child combinator, `>` in order to select direct children `li` elements:

```
$('#uSPStyle > li:eq(' + vFirst + ') ul li').length;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#uSPStyle li').eq(vFirst).find('li').length;
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/72hm33Lv/)**

This would get the length of the list items inside the top-level list item having the index from your URL parameter. I prefer the `eq()` method for simpler syntax.

Comment: `vFirst` is a query string in the Url. I would like to the LI that corresponds to the LI and see if it has a UL inside and get the length for that.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).eq(...).find(...).length is not a function`

Comment: Oops. Use `length` without the parens.

Comment: @Josh Crozier beat you to it :). I +1 your answer because this also works. Thank you.

Comment: Ohhhhh... ooops sorry. Let me test your code now :) I am sorry. Doing many things at once.

Answer (score 0):

```
var vFirst = "3";
console.log( $('#uSPStyle > li:eq(' + vFirst + ') ul li').length )
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sb6dgk2g/1/)**

Comment: I have to use `vFirst` to figure out which parent LI I have to check.

Comment: I updated my question. there are many LI and I want to check for a sub UL inside the nth parent LI.